# Does XCode creates one object for all empty strings?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

i've noticed that all @"" objects create one reference for all times it is executed.

```
NSString *s1=@"";
NSString *s2=@"";
```

In this sample s1 equals s2.

@"" will create one pointer in all cases, every time i use it?

Can i rely on this feature in comparing strings in objective-c?

Or simply, can i use this statement, if i want to assure that my string is empty:

```
 if(s == @""){
 //do something
 }
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that two empty strings will actually point to the same location in memory.  It is a compiler optimization that can be turned off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Objective C has an optimization in the compiler that simply points all equivalent string literals to the same string in memory to avoid allocating unnecessary resources. This feature is reliable but there is a chance that this will not always happen as documented in the Objective C language specs.

Comment: I also agree with Jesse that you should use isEqualToString

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
if([s isEqualToString:@""])
```

Comment: Yes, i know that i SHOULD use it. BUT if @"" creates one pointer to each emppty string - it means that i may use   if(s==@"")

Comment: @Krio: i was fairly ambiguous but I was trying to imply it is probably best not to count on that single pointer reference always being the case, memory may be reallocated etc.