# Unique Instances of NSString for empty or 1-char strings

Tags: objective-c

I would like to understand more about the way XCode/Objective-C handle constant strings.  I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693665/does-xcode-creates-one-object-for-all-empty-strings), but I would like more information.  Consider the following code:

```
NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[[_textFieldA stringValue] UTF8String]];
NSString *b = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[[_textFieldB stringValue] UTF8String]];
NSString *c = [a copy];
NSString *d = [a mutableCopy];
```

Note that the textFields are just a way to set the strings at runtime ensuring that the compiler doesn't get too smart on me and build in a single instance.

If my text fields are empty, or contain a single character such as "x" or "$", then a == b == c == the same constant NSString instance.  If I instead provide "xy", then a == c != b.  d is always unique, as one might expect since it is mutable.

Now normally this wouldn't be an issue, I'm not trying to modify the contents of these strings, however, I am working on a system where I frequently use objc_setAssociatedObject.  So here now I might come accross an empty string, and then set associated object data on it, and then have another empty string and collide with the first.

I have, for the moment, solved my issue by creating mutable strings instead.

So my questions:

1. Is this an Objective-C specification, or an XCode excentricity?
2. Does anyone know how the instance is determined?  Why "x" get's one instance, but not "xy"?  I would think some internal dictionary is involved and there's no good reason to stop at 1 character.
3. Is there a way to turn this off, so all empty strings are unique instances, or other suggestions?

I am using XCode 5.1.1, OSX 10.9.4, SDK 10.9.

Thank you!

Comment: NSString is a class cluster. It's hiding a lot of complexity.

Comment: Mike Ash wrote about this a bit. Google tagged pointers and Objective-C. In the meantime, don't worry about it. Use the isEqual: and isEqualTo: methods as appropriate. You should generally not need to do pointer comparison with Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this an Objective-C specification, or an XCode excentricity?

It is just implementation detail. Not documented any where. These kind of behaviour may changed in future without notice.

> Does anyone know how the instance is determined? Why "x" get's one instance, but not "xy"? I would think some internal dictionary is involved and there's no good reason to stop at 1 character.

No until someone able to access source code want to share the details with us.

> Is there a way to turn this off, so all empty strings are unique instances, or other suggestions?

No way to turn it off. Don't use `objc_setAssociatedObject` with `NSString`

---

As @Ken Thomases said in comment

> In general, it probably doesn't make sense to use objc_setAssociatedObject() with any value class.

Some other examples are `NSNumber`, `NSData` and `NSValue`. They are often cached and reused.

Comment: In general, it probably doesn't make sense to use `objc_setAssociatedObject()` with any value class. For a value class, an instance's "identity" is not supposed to matter, only its value (a.k.a. content).